# If vbYes/vbNo - Can you have another vb/Yes/vbNo questino if return on answer is Yes?

Tags: vba, ms-access, compiler-errors

I'm looking to create a tree from my initial If vbYes = msgbox("statement"). If the user selects YES, can that lead to an additional YES/NO msgbox?

```
If vbYes = MsgBox("Do you have Federal Employee Health Benefits (FEHBB), such as Blue Cross Blue Shield?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) Then
    If vbYes = MsgBox("Would you like to terminate/suspend your Federal Employee Health Benefits (FEHBB) while on orders?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) Then
        FEHBCancel = InputBox("Please initial here to cancel/suspend your FEHB.")
    Else
        KeepFEHB = InputBox("Please select if you would like to incur a debt (deductions would be doubled when you return to duty until the debt is paid off), or you can set-up payments through a separate checking account and continue to make payments.")
Else
    NoFEHB = InputBox("Please initial here indicating that you do not have Federal Employee Health Benefits.")
End If
```

I'm not sure how to line it up so I can do these statements and not get the end If error...

Comment: (edited) With proper indentation it should be clear where you're missing the End If

Comment: That does help a bit, thank you!

Comment: Rather than using a whole range of `MsgBox` and `InputBox` that are nested, you may want to consider using a small pop-up modal form. On it you can have some Option Groups of Radio Buttons, and some text boxes that have their visibility controlled by the state of the Option Groups.

Comment: If vbYes = MsgBox("Do you have Federal Employee Health Benefits (FEHBB), such as Blue Cross Blue Shield?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) Then
    End If
    If vbYes = MsgBox("Would you like to terminate/suspend your Federal Employee Health Benefits (FEHB) while on orders?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) Then
        FEHBCancel = InputBox("Please initial here to cancel/suspend your FEHB.")
   Else
    Keep = InputBox("Please initial here indicating that you do not have Federal Employee Health Benefits.")
    End If